# download file using helper magento

Tags: magento-1.8, downloadable

I want to make a functionality by which a user can download file of any type from my magento store. I have displayed file link. Is there any magento default helper by which I can make it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

please choose the correct file helper and make sure you using correct path on everywhere.

```
$linkfile = array();
$_highfilePath = $FolderPath.DS.$fname;
$linkfile[] = array(
        'file' => $filePath,
        'name' => $fname,
        'size' => filesize($filePath),
        'status' => 'new'
);

$linkFileName = Mage::helper('downloadable/file')->moveFileFromTmp(
            Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link::getBaseTmpPath(),
            Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link::getBasePath(),
            $linkfile
    );

    $linkModel = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link')->setData(array(
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'sort_order' => 0,
            'number_of_downloads' => 0, // Unlimited downloads
            'is_shareable' => 2, // Not shareable
            'link_url' => '',
            'link_type' => 'file',
            'link_file' => json_encode($linkfile),
            'sample_url' => $SamplePathUrl,
            'sample_file' => json_encode($linkfile),
            'sample_type' => 'file',
            'use_default_title' => true,
            'default_price' => 0,
            'price' => 0,
            'store_id' => 0,
            'website_id' => $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId(),
    ));
```

hope i help you.